# Oracle Pivot - converting values into columns

Tags: oracle11g, pivot

I have table in Oracle 11g with 3 fields:

```
 STUDYID  |  STUDY_PARAMETER  | STUDY_VALUE
```

---

```
  5268    |  Age Group        | ADULT (18-65)
  5269    |  Age Group        | ADULT (18-65)
  5270    |  Age Group        | ADULT (18-65)
  5271    |  Age Unit         | ADULT (18-65)    
  1668A   |  Trial Type       | ADULT (18-65)
  5273    |  Trial Type       | Dispensing
  5345    |  Age Unit         | Years
  1668AC  |  Age Group        | ADULTS (18-39)
```

So, what I need is to display values in this order:

```
STUDY_ID  |  AGE_GROUP     |  AGE_UNIT |  TRIAL_TYPE
```

---

```
  5268    |  ADULT (18-65) |  Years    | Dispensing
  5269    |  ADULT (18-65) |  (null)   | (null)
  1668AC  |  ADULTS (18-39)|  Years    | Non - Dispensing
```

and so on.

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
        SELECT STUDYID, STUDY_VALUE, STUDY_PARAMETER
        FROM   RD.STUDY_INFO
      )
PIVOT (
        SUM(STUDY_VALUE)
        FOR (STUDY_PARAMETER) 
        IN (
              'Age Unit' AS AGE_UNIT,
              'Age Group' AS AGE_GROUP,
              'Trial Type' AS TRIAL_TYPE
           )
      );
```

I learned this from examples on the net but I am not sure if I can use SUM() like this...?!

I get this error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I tried using MAX() aggregate fun and it seems like it is working. im testing it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `STUDY_VALUE` column appears to be a string, you will need to use either the `max()` or `min()` aggregate function on the values:

```
SELECT *
FROM  
(
  SELECT STUDYID, STUDY_VALUE, STUDY_PARAMETER
  FROM   STUDY_INFO
)
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(STUDY_VALUE)
  FOR (STUDY_PARAMETER) IN ('Age Unit' AS AGE_UNIT,
                              'Age Group' AS AGE_GROUP,
                              'Trial Type' AS TRIAL_TYPE)
);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9682a/2)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this query.

```
SELECT 
ID,
MAX(Case When parameter='Age Group' then Value else '0' end) AS  AgeGroup,
MAX(Case When parameter='Trial Type' then Value else '0'end)AS  TrialType,
MAX(Case When parameter='Age Unit' then Value else '0'end)AS  AgeUnit
FROM teststack
GROUP BY ID 
ORDER BY ID
```