# transpose and compare column values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, transpose

Assume i have a 2x5 table like this.

```
105 blue    green black  red
106 red     green white  red
```

i want to transpose this table and compare the values from two columns and display if they are the same in the third column.Like this

```
105     106    notsame
blue    red    notsame
green   green  same
black   white  notsame
red     red    same
```

I tried and achieved this using a lot of "unions". But how do i do it with less complexity and code size?

Comment: Are you saying your table will never have more than 2 rows in it?

Comment: Thats right. I will not get more than two rows even though the number of columns might change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the columns into rows, which means you need to unpivot them. I'm working with a table defined as:

```
create table t42(id number, colour1 varchar2(5), colour2 varchar2(5),
  colour3 varchar2(5), colour4 varchar2(5));
```

With your two rows of data, you can unpivot it to 10 rows, one per column per row:

```
select *
from (
  select id, to_char(id) as cid, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4
  from t42
)
unpivot (val for col in (cid, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4));

        ID COL     VAL                                    
---------- ------- ----------------------------------------
       105 CID     105                                      
       105 COLOUR1 blue                                     
       105 COLOUR2 green                                    
       105 COLOUR3 black                                    
       105 COLOUR4 red                                      
       106 CID     106                                      
       106 COLOUR1 red                                      
       106 COLOUR2 green                                    
       106 COLOUR3 white                                    
       106 COLOUR4 red
```

You can then effectively re-pivot that:

```
select col,
  max(case when rn = 1 then val end) as val1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then val end) as val2
from (
  select u.*, row_number() over (partition by u.col order by u.id) as rn
  from (
    select id, to_char(id) as cid, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4
    from t42
  ) unpivot (val for col in (cid, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4)) u
)
group by col;

COL     VAL1  VAL2
------- ----- -----
CID     105   106   
COLOUR1 blue  red   
COLOUR2 green green 
COLOUR3 black white 
COLOUR4 red   red
```

I added a `row_number` pseudo-column to the unpivot result, and used that to split the values into one of two columns; and then used `max` to collapse the empty values.

And then you just need to sompare the values in the two columns:

```
select val1, val2,
  case when val1 = val2 then 'same' else 'notsame' end as compare
from (
  select col,
    max(case when rn = 1 then val end) as val1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then val end) as val2
  from (
    select u.*, row_number() over (partition by u.col order by u.id) as rn
    from (
      select id, to_char(id) as cid, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4
      from t42
    ) unpivot (val for col in (cid, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4)) u
  )
  group by col
);

VAL1  VAL2  COMPARE
----- ----- -------
105   106   notsame 
blue  red   notsame 
green green same    
black white notsame 
red   red   same
```

If you add more columns you'll just need to modify the inner unpivot part.

I said you were effectively re-pivoting, but you can actually re-pivot too; I think this the other way looks impler, persoanlly, but this might perform better and opinions will vary anyway:

```
select a_val, b_val,
  case when a_val = b_val then 'same' else 'notsame' end as compare
from (
  select * from (
    select col, val, rn
    from (
      select u.*, row_number() over (partition by u.col order by u.id) as rn
      from (
        select id, to_char(id) as cid, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4
        from t42
      ) unpivot (val for col in (cid, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4)) u
    )
  )
  pivot (max(val) as val for (rn) in (1 as a, 2 as b))
);

A_VAL B_VAL COMPARE
----- ----- -------
105   106   notsame 
blue  red   notsame 
green green same    
black white notsame 
red   red   same
```

If the IDs (or whatever they are) are fixed you can use those instead of `rn`, but I get the impression they might change.

---

As an unasked-for variation, you could compare values in different columns, sort of. Say the data was set up like:

```
insert into t42 values (105, 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'red');
insert into t42 values (106, 'red', 'green', 'white', 'blue');
```

... so now both rows have both `red` and `blue`, but in different columns. You could rank the values based on their name rather than using the column name:

```
select val1, val2,
  case when val1 = val2 then 'same' else 'notsame' end as compare
from (
  select col_rnk,
    max(case when rn = 1 then val end) as val1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then val end) as val2
  from (
    select u.*,
      row_number() over (partition by u.col order by u.id) as rn,
      rank() over (order by case when u.col = 'CID' then null else u.val end)
        as col_rnk
    from (
      select id, to_char(id) as cid, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4
      from t42
    ) unpivot (val for col in (cid, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4)) u
  )
  group by col_rnk
)
order by val1;

VAL1  VAL2  COMPARE
----- ----- -------
105   106   notsame 
black       notsame 
blue  blue  same    
green green same    
red   red   same    
      white notsame
```

I've just added the `col_rnk` pseudo-column; with a special case for the ID column, but then you might not want that displayed anyway. Getting `black` and `white`, or any other mismatched pair, into the same result row would need another level of manipulation.

Comment: Looks like a great solution. Thanks for all the detail!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use pivot. You can check out [Oracle info on pivot in 11g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)

I don't have access to 11g yet, so I can't work up an example. But I know about it and that does what you want.

Here is SQL from that link:

```
select * from (
   select times_purchased, state_code
   from customers t
)
pivot 
(
   count(state_code)
   for state_code in ('NY','CT','NJ','FL','MO')
)
order by times_purchased
```

Here is another [SO answer which may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116354/oracle-pivot-converting-values-into-columns)

Or perhaps better, here are all the [PIVOT and ORACLE tagged items on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pivot+oracle)

And finally, found [another thread on Oracle's forum](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1020045) which might help create the simple transpose. 2 "Helpful" answers at the bottom.

Comment: i saw that post earlier. I had some trouble relating that example with mine. I guess i'm looking for something less complex.
can you tell what are the changes i need to make in my example?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. Hopefully someone with 11g experience will answer.