# Display rows as columns in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, pivot

Need your help in below, i have to achieve below target from my table.

EMP Table

```
Record Id    EMP Id    Emp Name    Emp Dept
--------     -------   -------     --------
     1        123        ABC         Sales
     2     -  231        PQR         DEPT
```

I want output in below format

```
Record ID     Table Name   Column Name  column Values
--------      ----------   -----------  -------------
1              EMP          EMP Id      123
1              EMP          Emp Name    ABC
1              EMP          EMP Dept    Sales
```

Is this output possible, would be very thankful if someone can provide query with example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Pivot - converting values into columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116354/oracle-pivot-converting-values-into-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this with a temporary table.

temp table schema

```
Record ID     Table Name   Column Name  column Values
```

QUERY

```
BEGIN

FOR t IN (SELECT table_name,column_name
          FROM all_tab_columns
          WHERE table_name='MyTable' and owner='MySchema' and column_name<>'RecordId' ) LOOP

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
          'INSERT INTO temp_table SELECT RecordId,'''||t.table_name||''','''||t.column_name||''','||t.column_name||' FROM ' ||  t.table_name;
      END LOOP;
COMMIT;  
END;

/

SELECT *
FROM temp_table
ORDER BY "RecordId";
```