# Query to turn field names/values rows as a single row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm working with a system that allows users to create their own fields.  This is implemented in Oracle as a field table and then a field/value table.  If I run a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  field_name, field_value
FROM field_t
INNER JOIN field_t ON field_t.id = field_string_t.field_id
WHERE (field_name = 'foo'
  OR field_name = 'bar'
  OR field_name = 'buzz'
)
```

then I can get the field name/value pairs in a series of rows:

```
id      field_name    field_value
8       foo           1
8       bar           5
8       buzz          4
... and so on for each id
```

How can I write a query to return this instead:

```
id      foo      bar      buzz
8       1        5        4
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: This is called *pivoting* - see eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116354/oracle-pivot-converting-values-into-columns

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Mark Bannister you could use the PIVOT function to do the same

If you want to use a sub-query instead of values for field_name use PIVOT XML(Note the result will be in XML in this case)

For more information please check the below link

[PIVOT and UNPIVOT operators in Oracle 11g](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php)

```
 select * from
 (
 SELECT id, field_name, field_value,field_id
 FROM   field_t)
 PIVOT  (
 MAX(field_value) 
 FOR (field_name) IN ('foo' as foo, 'bar' AS bar, 'buzz' as buzz))
 WHERE id=field_id;
```